# I'm trying to deserialize an XML and getting null for some of the attributes

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-deserialization, emf, ecore

I'm trying to deserialize the below XML to an object, but one of the values (**Required**)is returning null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<sy:config xmlns:sy="http://www.example.com/def/sy">
 -<sy:configurations>
  -<sy:configuration property="isReq" name="ABC">
    **Required**
    <atom:link title="ABC Uri" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="http://www.example.com/def//id" 
    href="abc/bc/def/docid"/>
   </sy:configuration>
 </sy:configurations>
</sy:config>
enter code here
```

I'm using the below code to deserialize eclipse emfutil to deserialize could you please let me know why the configuration.getvalue() is returning null instead of returning 'Required'

```
private static <T extends EObject> T readEObjectFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream, String emfFileExtension,Class<T> expectedResultType) throws IOException {
        org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI emfResourceUri = org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI
                .createPlatformResourceURI(FILE_PATH + emfFileExtension, true);
        Resource emfResource = new ResourceSetImpl().createResource(emfResourceUri);

        emfResource.load(inputStream, null);
        EObject eObject = emfResource.getContents().get(0);

        T result = expectedResultType.cast(eObject);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, where is 'configuration.getvalue()' in this code?

Comment: Please specify what is `expectedResultType` and what happens inside `expectedResultType.cast`

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: Instead of wasting reputation on a bounty, you might just want to clarify your question a bit. The XML you've pasted is not valid XML - you probably copied it from some GUI and some of the formatting came along with it.

Secondly, Why are you using EMF for this? Why not just the standard Java XML libraries? You'll find much more information online on that then on a vendor-specific product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201505/) post on the Eclipse forums has an example of how to do this, and a discussion of several reasons why it might not be working.

Here's the full example:

```
try {       ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
            Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("http:///My.chbasev21"));
            DocumentRoot documentRoot = ChbaseV21Factory.eINSTANCE.createDocumentRoot();
            CompanyDetailsType root = ChbaseV21Factory.eINSTANCE.createCompanyDetailsType();
            documentRoot.setCompanyDetails(root);
            resource.getContents().add(documentRoot);
            //resource.save(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
            resource.save(System.out, null);
            resource.save(new FileOutputStream("C:/test2.xml"), null);
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
```